# Redefine function's 'toString' and 'valueOf'

Tags: javascript, function

I defined a prototype function 'isElement' of Node and I want to make it works like 'div.isElement' return 'true'.

```
<div id="dom1">someText
    <p>This is p1 of <span class="bold">dom1</span></p>
</div>

Node.prototype.isElement = (function(){
    var result;
    var fn = function(){
        console.log(obj);
        result = (this.nodeType == 1 ? true : false);
        return result;
    };
    fn.toString = fn.valueOf = function(){
        return result;
    };
    return fn;
})();

var dom1 = document.getElementById('dom1');
dom1.isElement();  //true
dom1.isElement;  //true
```

If the 'dom1' never call the function 'isElement()',then 'dom1.isElement' return 'undefined'. I understand why it return 'undefined',but I want to know how to makes it return 'true' or 'false' when 'isElement()' never be called.

I just want to use it like:

```
if(dom1.isElement){//do something}
```

but not like:

```
if(dom1.isElement()){//do something}
```

waiting for answers , thanks.

Comment: Not possible as I am aware of, unless you change `isElement` to be a boolean property, and modify all the methods that would affect this `isElement` boolean. There really is no point in going through that trouble; the overhead is negligible. Just use it as a method call. (I'm referring specifically to the last part)

Comment: Just as a general note, extending the DOM is not considered to be a good idea. And btw, `if (dom1.isElement)` would **always** evaluate to `true`, since it is a (function) object (no matter what you let `toString` return).

Comment: You are assuming that DOM elements implement prototype inheritance and that you can modify the constructor's prototype. Neither are good assumptions, since there is no requirement for browsers (or host environments in general) to implement prototype inheritance and some don't.

Comment: Seems like a lot of work just to replace "if (dom1.nodeType === 1) {..." with a method call. If you just want to make the call clearer for documentation purposes, just make it "if (dom1.nodeType === ELEMENT_NODE) {..."

Comment: That architecture makes no sense. All nodes will inherit their `isElement` property from whatever was the result of the last call. So if you do `dom1.firstChild.isElement` after the other code, it returns `true`, and `dom1.firstChild.isElement()` will return `false`.

Comment: @user4815162342—or to have an `isElement` function that returns true or false depending on the NodeType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a property that has your function as the getter:

```
Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype, "isElement", {
    get: function() {
        var result = this.nodeType == 1;
        return result;
    }
});
```

Comment: Presumably you are only interested in Gecko–based browsers.

Comment: @RobG Actually, all ES-5 compatible browsers should have this.

Comment: Be aware that `result` is global. You probably just want `return this.nodeType === 1;`.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah I was copy pasting. Fixed.

Comment: @RobG Yes,I don't need it to run in IE,Gecko–based browsers is enough

Comment: @Roger As I've mentioned to Rob earlier, this works with IE8+, FF4+ and all Webkit browsers, not just Gecko.

Comment: @Asad—Yes: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd548687(v=vs.94).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd548687(v=vs.94).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the JavaScript language makes no guarantees that the DOM implementation provides the standard JS object facilities.

That said, if you have determined that your environment always supports these then a getter is called for in this case, effectively you can write a function which is called whenever a specific property value is requested.

Refer to [MDN](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects.html#Defining_getters_and_setters) for the details :

```
Node.prototype.__defineGetter__('isElement', 
  function () { return this.nodeType === 1; });
```

Test it with your browser at http://jsfiddle.net/L5hBq/

Comment: +1 but not a fan of the strategy. It disguises function calls as property access. What happens when a user does `dom1.isElement = true;`? To me getters and setters should be used to maintain state or dependencies, or to synchronise data, so better make the property readonly and throw if assigned to.

Comment: I'm not overly keen myself - caveat emptor. Setting `dom1.isElement` causes no problem (at least on Chrome) as I did not define a setter. Updated the fiddle to test this : http://jsfiddle.net/L5hBq/1

Comment: defineGetter is both non-standard and deprecated.